# remove certain symbols form a string array

Tags: python, string, numpy

I have a numpy.ndarray with Strings. I have created a character list, which I would like to use against the strings array, to remove all characters which appear in the character list. I want to put the symbol free strings in a new array. How can I do this?

Input:

```
symbols = string.printable[62:]
symbolsList = list(symbols)
symbolsList
```

Output:

```
['!',
 '"',
 '#',
 '$',
 '%',
 '&',
 "'",
 '(',
 ')',
 '*',
 '+',
 ',',
 '-',
 '.',
 '/',
 ':',
 ';',
 '<',
 '=',
 '>',
 '?',
 '@',
 '[',
 '\\',
 ']',
 '^',
 '_',
 '`',
 '{',
 '|',
 '}',
 '~',
 ' ',
 '\t',
 '\n',
 '\r',
 '\x0b',
 '\x0c']
```

A sample output of the `string_array`:

```
array(['[KFC] CHicken_Gravy_Coke_Biscuit This is my Order!!!<lf><lf>', dtype=object)
```

I want it to look like this:

```
  array(['KFC CHicken Gravy Coke Biscuit This is my Order  lf lf', dtype=object)
```

I tried:

```
cleanData = []
for i in string_array:
        cleanData.append(string_array[i].replace(symbolsList[i], " "))
```

and:

```
cleanData = []
for i in summary_data:
    cleanData = summary_data[i].replace(symbolsList[i], " ")
```

Both give same Output:

```
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

But does not work :( How to make this work? Or do what I want?

Comment: you need to know that when you are iterating over ``summary_data``, then ``i`` will not give you index. It will give you the elements directly. For example, if you have a list, ``lst = [6, 8, 5]``, in the first interation of ``for i in lst:``, you will have ``i==6``, in the second ``i==8``, in the third ``i==5``. This means that it does not make any sense to use ``i`` as an index.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way.

```
import re, string, numpy as np

def remove_chars_re(x):
    x = re.sub('[' + re.escape(''.join(string.printable[62:])) + ']', ' ', x)
    return re.sub(' +', ' ', x).strip()

arr = np.array(['[KFC] CHicken_Gravy_Coke_Biscuit This is my Order!!!<lf><lf>'], dtype=object)

list(map(remove_chars_re, arr))

# ['KFC CHicken Gravy Coke Biscuit This is my Order lf lf']
```

**Explanation**

- The first `re.sub` removes unwanted characters with a single space.
- The second `re.sub` removes double spaces.
- `strip()` removes whitespace from start and end of the string.

Comment: What about the symbols in the character list? @jpp

Comment: @cool_beans, sorry I don't understand. Is the desired output not what you expect?

Comment: Oh, sorry it works :) So what if I dont want it to print the string as a list of characters? I want to keep the string form, because it prints like so: `[
 'K',
 'F',
 'C']

Comment: @cool_beans, in my full example, output is a list of strings, e.g. `['KFC CHicken Gravy Coke Biscuit This is my Order lf lf']`

Comment: for me its each letter is its own entity, because I put it through a for loop to remove_chars_re for each string in my list

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would go about it.

- Iterate over each string, `str`
- Iterate over each undesired charactered, `chr`, for each `str` (Nested Loop)
- Use the `str.replace(chr, '')`

Here is the code.

```
cleanData = []

for str in string_array:
    tmp_str = str #you need to do this because you need to filter every character one by one

    for chr in symbolsList:
        tmp_str = tmp_str.replace(chr, ' ') #if you want to replace your undesired symbols with a space

    cleanData.append(tmp_str)
```